# SSIS no genera Excel trabajando con gran cantidad de registros

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con un SSIS, que basicamente recupera los datos de una tabla y los exporta a un Excel. El problema es que cuando trabajo con una cantidad limitada de registros (1000 registros) me genera el Excel sin problemas, pero cuando le quito el top e intento generarlo con el total de los registros no me genera el archivo.

Estoy trabajando con version 2008 y al SSIS lo llamo a traves de un job SQL.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás controlando tu `Error Logging`?

Comment: No entiendo tu consulta Davlio, podrias explicarte un poco mejor? El Log del Job muestra que se ejecuto correctamente, pero al revisar la ruta en donde deberia estar el archivo me encuentro con que este no esta.

Comment: `xls` tiene una limitación de 65.000 líneas. Si lo esportas en este formato, lo deberías cambiar por `xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo me paso algo parecido...
lo que pasa es que los archivos excel (`.xls`) tienen un **máximo de `rows` permitidos** segun tu versión de excel...

revisa en esta tabla cual es tu versión y el máximo de `rows` permitidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero te ayude!